# Export to Excel: Index outside bounds of array

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

Thank you @Blackwood and @Mary. Still receiving the error but I'm on its trail. Corrected code is substituted below

Mary: As you suggested...

I reset the StringSplitOptions return options to None on both the "For Each" line, and the "Dim _LogParts()" line.

I changed the variable in "xlWorkSheet.Cells(_Row, _DT_HDR) ="  from  "_LogParts(3)"  to my pre-formatted variable  "_ANY_DT"

```
 I'm not sure why I need to do the LogEntry.Split twice however...
```

Blackwood: Following your suggestion:

I added a msgbox to show what was being assigned to each of the 4 variables.

The result for the first run looks like this:

UserID = Admin

Role = UU

Event = Open

Time Stamp = xx/xx/xxxx ##:##:##

However, every subsequent line in the output looks like this:

UserID =

Admin

Role = UU

Event = Open

Time Stamp = xx/xx/xxxx ##:##:##

I'm unable to figure out why the UserID text ("Admin") is wrapping to the second line everytime but the first time, however I'm reasonably certain that's my problem. In the Excel sheet, the first line uses a standard height row but all subsequent rows are double height. I believe if I can stop the wrapping, I have my solution.

Original (edited) query:

A standalone I work with generates an ever increasing log of data and publishes it in a grid format to a dropdown textbox. I'm tasked with writing VB code to export the data from the textbox to Excel. The code below does export everything in the log but I get the "Index outside bounds of array" error and none of my formatting gets applied. I get a clean breakpoint right before the Next command. I get the error first if I move the breakpoint one line below it.

The log data is posted by a plugin to a dropdown textbox in an input screen. It appears like this:

```
admin,FS,OPEN,3/21/2018 9:06:39 AM
admin,FS,SAVE,3/21/2018 9:10:29 AM
admin,FS,SAVE,3/21/2018 9:10:32 AM
admin,FS,SAVE,3/21/2018 9:13:37 AM
admin,FS,SAVE,3/21/2018 9:14:42 AM
admin,FS,CLOSE,3/21/2018 9:14:43 AM
```

The output to Excel using the code below is supposed to look like this:
(without formatting)

```
UserTouchesFX™ by MortgageTech©         
March 29, 2018 @ 10:51 AM           
UserID  Role  Event Date Time
admin   FS    OPEN  3/21/2018 9:06
admin   FS    SAVE  3/21/2018 9:10
admin   FS    SAVE  3/21/2018 9:10
admin   FS    SAVE  3/21/2018 9:13
admin   FS    SAVE  3/21/2018 9:14
admin   FS    CLOSE 3/21/2018 9:14
```

Below is the edited button code I'm (still) working on:

```
    Dim xlApp As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("It appears that Excel is not available at this time." & vbCrLf & _
        "You may need to close all instances of Excel and try again." & vbCrLf & _
        "If that doesn't work, you may need to reboot your computer." & vbCrLf & _
        "If that doesn't work, there may be a problem with Excel")
    End If

    Dim xlWorkBook  As Object
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Object

    Dim _USERID_HDR     As Integer = 1
    Dim _ASSOCROLE_HDR  As Integer = 2
    Dim _EVENT_HDR      As Integer = 3
    Dim _DT_HDR         As Integer = 4

' Start Data at _Row
    Dim _Row            As Integer = 4 
    Dim _Delimiter()    As String = {","}

            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
            xlApp.Visible       = True 
            xlApp.UserControl   = True
            xlWorkBook          = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
            xlWorkSheet         = xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet()

' Add table headers going cell by cell.

            xlWorkSheet.Cells((_Row - 3), 1).Value = String.Format("UserTouchesFX{0} by MortgageTech{1}", Chr(0153), Chr(0169))
            xlWorkSheet.Cells((_Row - 2), 1).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy @ hh:mm tt")
            xlWorkSheet.Cells((_Row - 1), _USERID_HDR).Value    = "User ID"
            xlWorkSheet.Cells((_Row - 1), _ASSOCROLE_HDR).Value = "Role"
            xlWorkSheet.Cells((_Row - 1), _EVENT_HDR).Value     = "Event"
            xlWorkSheet.Cells((_Row - 1), _DT_HDR).Value        = "Date Time"

' Assign Log Items to specific Excel cells 

    Try
    For Each _LogEntry As String in (FX_AU_Sessions_Log.Text.Split(New Char() { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))

        Dim  _ANY_DT        As DateTime             = Nothing
        Dim  _LogParts()    As String               = _LogEntry.Split( _Delimiter, StringSplitOptions.None)
        DateTime.TryParse(_LogParts(3), _ANY_DT)

            xlWorkSheet.Cells(_Row, _USERID_HDR)    = _LogParts(0)  'User ID
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(_Row, _ASSOCROLE_HDR) = _LogParts(1)  'User Role
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(_Row, _EVENT_HDR)     = _LogParts(2)  'Event
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(_Row, _DT_HDR)        = _ANY_DT       'Time Stamp

        _Row = _Row + 1

' MsgBox ( _
' "UserID   = " &   _LogParts(0)    & vbCrLf & _
' "Role         =   _LogParts(0)    & vbCrLf & _
' "Event        =   _LogParts(0)    & vbCrLf & _
' "TimeStamp    =   _ANY_DT         & vbCrLf & _
' )

     Next _LogEntry

' Format Settings:
' ColorIndex values: 0 Auto, 1 Black, 2 White, 3 Red, 5 Blue, 6 Yellow, '10 Green, 40 Tan, 34 Light Turquoise, 35 Light Green, 36 Light Yellow, '37 Pale Blue
' Set first row to Bold Font Size 16 - Top Company Name Row | 
' Vertical Alignment: Top  = -4160, Center = -4108, Bottom = -4107
' Horizont Alignment: Left = -4131, Center = -4108,  Right = -4152

       With xlWorkSheet.Range("A1", "D1")
            .Interior.ColorIndex        = 35
            .Merge("A1", "D1")
            .Font.Size = 16
            .Font.Bold = True
            .VerticalAlignment          = -4107 
            .HorizontalAlignment        = -4108
       End With

' Set second row to Regular Font Size 12 - Date Now Row
       With xlWorkSheet.Range("A2", "D2")      
            .Interior.ColorIndex        = 34
            .Merge("A2", "D2")
            .Font.Size                  = 12
            .Font.Bold                  = False
            .VerticalAlignment          = -4107 
            .HorizontalAlignment        = -4108
       End With

' Set third row to Bold Font Size 12 - Column Header Row
       With xlWorkSheet.Range("A3", "D3")
            .Interior.ColorIndex        = 15
            .Font.Size                  = 11
            .Font.Bold                  = True
            .VerticalAlignment          = -4107 
            .HorizontalAlignment        = -4108
'           .EntireColumn.AutoFit
       End With

' Set column widths
        With xlWorkSheet
            .Columns("A").ColumnWidth   = 20
            .Columns("B").ColumnWidth   = 10
            .Columns("C").ColumnWidth   = 20
            .Columns("D").ColumnWidth   = 40
            .Rows.WrapText = False
        End With

' Set column formatting
        With xlWorkSheet
            .Columns("A").EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = -4131 ' Left
            .Columns("B").EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = -4108 ' Center
            .Columns("C").EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = -4108 ' Center
            .Columns("D").EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = -4152 ' Right
            .Columns("D").NumberFormat  = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm AM/PM"
        End With

    Catch Ex As Exception

        Macro.Alert(String.Format("There is problem with xlWorkBook: {0}", Ex.Message ))

    End Try
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input data, and what output format you want to achieve?

Comment: Certainly, the data is posted to a Dropdown Textbox and looks like this:

admin,FS,OPEN,3/21/2018 9:06:39 AM
admin,FS,SAVE,3/21/2018 9:10:29 AM
admin,FS,SAVE,3/21/2018 9:10:32 AM
admin,FS,SAVE,3/21/2018 9:13:37 AM
admin,FS,SAVE,3/21/2018 9:14:42 AM
admin,FS,CLOSE,3/21/2018 9:14:43 AM


Output to excel looks like this:
UserTouchesFX™ by MortgageTech©   
March 29, 2018 @ 10:51 AM   
User ID Role Event Date Time
admin FS OPEN 3/21/2018 9:06
"

Comment: Thanks - suggest that you edit your original question, so that it's self contained and the formatting of the output data is easier to read.

Comment: Made the edits requested to my original post. Learning fast on both fronts. Hope that's what you had in mind. Thanks

Comment: If there is no error before the first time you hit the `Next` statement. but you get the error before you hit the statement after the `Next`, then the error is happening inside the for loop, just not on the first time through the loop. Either step through the instructions in the loop until you reach the error, or examine the variables at the time the error occurs to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The only index out of range I can see is with this line

```
 Dim  _LogParts() As String  = _LogEntry.Split( _Separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

The removal of an empty entry would result in a different size _LogParts array and when you used the elements of this array _LogParts(3) would be out of range and data can end up in the wrong column.
Unrelated but odd is

```
DateTime.TryParse(_LogParts(3), _ANY_DT)
```

_Any_DT doesn't appear to ever be used.